# windows 8 XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, windows-8, com, windows-store-apps, xmldocument

Suddenly all the xmldocment.LoadFromUriAsync(new uri("url")); gave me this exception
"HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."
in all my windows 8 store app aplications, even in the ones previously installed 
help ! :(

Comment: is the XML document local or does it access a public URI endpoint?  If the latter, is the endpoint behaving?  Perhaps set up [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home) to see if there's an unexpected return prompting a COM exception.

Comment: Hi Jim, it's a public uri, and when i put the url string in browser it returns xml normally, on other pc's i run the same solution and it works fine :(

Answer (score 0):

i worked it around , i used HttpClient.GetStringAsync(Uri); , then loaded it in XmlDocument
the xml that used to come from the webservice didn't start with  tag
it just came  tag, maybe that was the issue
i don't know :)